# Subdomains regarding name servers/domains

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, nameserver, virtualhost

I know how to configure subdomains like `sub.example.com` on Apache etc. My question is, do I need to make any changes to the name servers/domain that is provided to me?

Would it work the same as `domain.com/sub`?

Worth noting that I use `http://za.net/` as my domain provider (free domain) and zone edit as the name server provider which is also free. I think `.za.net` provides third-level domains, because when you register it, it becomes `example.za.net`.

I'm not 100% sure that it provides third-level domains, but would I need to make any changes with that? Or would the setup in my Apache config as a subdomain for `sub.example.za.net` work without need to do anything with the domain DNS or name servers?

`http://co.za/` is the same, but you pay for it. It's the premium domain provider in South Africa, but I've seen many sites with `sub.example.co.za` for example.

Anyway... ultimately my question is: Would creating virtual hosts and stuff for a subdomain like `sub.domain.com` be sufficient? and would I need to change anything in the name servers or domain DNS management tools?

The `sub.domain.com` would read the "sub" folder in the htdocs.

Comment: Not webmaster's question

Answer (score -2):

> my ultimate question is, would creating virtualhosts and stuff for a subdomain like sub.domain.com be sufficient?

No

1. You create **not subdomains**, but **hosts in domain** - RTFM right terms and difference between both
2. You have to add all this hosts in base domain, in order to provide A address (any way) for client, which later asks your Apache about your virualhost for needed hostname

Comment: Sorry, but if you're going to throw around terms like RTFM please link to a manual for people to read. On top of that, searching for your term "hosts in domain" didn't bring me back anything particularly useful compared with the more industry standard "subdomain" which brings back useful results about configuring both your web- and name-servers.